# Does the derivative of a function need to be continuous if the function is differentiable

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem:

[image]

I know the following:

**I.** It must be true because if f(7) was not continuous (undefined), then the difference of quotients would not be 4, but undefined

**II.** It must be true because the difference of quotients is equal to the derivative. The derivative at 7 exists (which is 4), so it must be differentiable.

**III.** This is the one where I am not certain. I know a derivative at x = 7 must exists, but I am not sure if it is continuous.

How do you know if the derivative of function is continuous at a certain point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative does not need to be continuous. Here is a standard example of this phenomenon: $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$. It is easy to see this function can be extended differentiably to take the value $0$ at $0$. However, the derivative blows up at $0$.

It is also true that derivatives always have the intermediate value property, even though they are discontinuous. Both of these are well-explored on this site in other questions.

Comment: Are there any simpler examples to show this?

Answer (score 0):

To have a concrete counterexample to that, as @Alfred Yerger has suggested, one takes $f(x)=(x-7)^{2}\sin(1/(x-7))+4(x-7)$ and $f(7)=0$, then $f'(7)=4$, and $f'(x)=2(x-7)\sin(1/(x-7))-\cos(1/(x-7))+4$ for $x\ne 7$. So there would be a problem for $\lim_{x\rightarrow 7}f'(x)$.